# Unnecessary option when decrypting HDD before booting

Tags: macos, startup, filevault, encryption

I've just performed a clean install of OS X Yosemite 10.10.3 on my new hard drive. Before installing i formatted the disk as an **encrypted** drive. When i start up my machine now i get to select between my account and button showing a question mark stating *update required* before the actual booting starts. I assume this is for decrypting the drive. When selecting my personal account the machine boots right into the operating system without a detour. When selecting the question mark i get prompted to select my personal account after the process of booting is finished.

I am certain that this unnecessary second option is due to the encryption of the hard drive as it first showed after restarting during the installation process when no user account had yet been created. However i have no idea how to get rid of it. Help therefore is appreciated.

Comment: see http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/152271/user-update-needed-after-updating-to-mac-os-x-yosemite?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. Decrypting and Encrypting it again solved it for me. Also nicely explained in the last post.

Comment: Cool, glad it worked. I'm going to flag this question as a dupe of that one, in that case, which will permalink the 2 questions & give future Googlers double the chance of finding a solution. It doesn't reflect on the quality of the question, just improves future searches.